# jsp session attribute

Tags: java, jsp

Jsp spec say that `session` attribute in `page` directive is set to `true` by default and thus we get the implicit `session` object reference.

Does this mean that the container always creates a session object for the jsp, even if a session is not required?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means (unless the session already exists of course).

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the clarification